# Convert html content to PDF Byte Array with kotlin

Tags: kotlin, base64, html-to-pdf

```
 val sanitizedHTML = Jsoup.clean(html, whitelist)
 val textRenderer = ITextRenderer()
 val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
 textRenderer.setDocumentFromString(sanitizedHTML)
 textRenderer.layout()
 textRenderer.createPDF(outputStream)
 textRenderer.finishPDF()
 return Base64.getDecoder().decode(outputStream.toByteArray())
```

I would like to generate pdf from html content and rather than saving as file, would like to upload to server which expects it to be ByteArray.

I tried to do above using jsoup to clean html and textRenderer for generating pdf but keep receiving error about invalid Base64 character 25.  Could someone help what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Why are you using Base64 decoder?

Comment: When I do not use Base64 decoder, i got some string value which looked like it was encoded, thats why. Is it not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

```
return Base64.getDecoder().decode(outputStream.toByteArray())
```

This was incorrect, if I remove Base64 decoding it is working well.